# How to register custom PositionStrategy from @angular/cdk/overlays

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2, angular-cdk

There's this example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KssNGRhyLRbRzEN59P4C?p=preview

It uses @angular/material `MdMenu` and utilizes `ConnectedPositionStrategy`  from @angular/cdk/overlays

```js
let originWithFallbackPosition = ConnectedPositionStrategy.prototype.withFallbackPosition;

ConnectedPositionStrategy.prototype.withFallbackPosition = function (originPos, overlayPos) {
    overlayPos.overlayX = 'start';
    if(this._preferredPositions.length) {
       return this;
    }
    return originWithFallbackPosition.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

But this changes the prototype I would like to use inheritance instead:

```js
export class MultiMenuPositionStrategy extends ConnectedPositionStrategy {
     public withFallbackPosition(originPos: OriginConnectionPosition, overlayPos: OverlayConnectionPosition) {
         overlayPos.overlayX = 'start';
         if(this._preferredPositions.length) {
             return this;
         }
         return super.withFallbackPosition(originPos, overlayPos);
     } 
 }
```

But then how do I register this class for use in this menu? I don
't see any methods in the API to register this custom PositionStrategy and using NgModule providers doesn't work.